# Why doesn't Microsoft OneDrive appear as a remote location in nautilus when I add it via GNOME Online Accounts?

Tags: 20.04, online-accounts

Why doesn't Microsoft OneDrive appear as a remote location in nautilus when I add it via GNOME Online Accounts (while e.g. Google Drive does) ?

[image]

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]